# Most Common (Max) Items in JSON data

Tags: python, json, dictionary, data-science

How can I split this JSON data into groups according to 'name' and sum the number of 'items' in each group in order to find the most common name (based on number of items). The `JSON` data I am working with is as follows:

```
json_data= [   
 {'code': '0101010G0AAABAB',
  'items': 2,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Co-Magaldrox_Susp 195mg/220mg/5ml S/F',
  'nic': 5.98,
  'act_cost': 5.56,
  'quantity': 1000},
 {'code': '0101021B0AAAHAH',
  'items': 1,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Alginate_Raft-Forming Oral Susp S/F',
  'nic': 1.95,
  'act_cost': 1.82,
  'quantity': 500},
 {'code': '0101021B0AAALAL',
  'items': 12,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Sod Algin/Pot Bicarb_Susp S/F',
  'nic': 64.51,
  'act_cost': 59.95,
  'quantity': 6300},
 {'code': '0101021B0AAAPAP',
  'items': 3,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Sod Alginate/Pot Bicarb_Tab Chble 500mg',
  'nic': 9.21,
  'act_cost': 8.55,
  'quantity': 180},
 {'code': '0101021B0BEADAJ',
  'items': 6,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Gaviscon Advance_Liq (Peppermint) S/F',
  'nic': 28.92,
  'act_cost': 26.84,
  'quantity': 90},
 {'code': '0101021B0BEAIAL',
  'items': 15,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Gaviscon Advance_Liq (Peppermint) S/F',
  'nic': 82.62,
  'act_cost': 76.67,
  'quantity': 7800},
 {'code': '0101021B0BEAQAP',
  'items': 5,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Gaviscon Advance_Liq (Peppermint) S/F',
  'nic': 13.47,
  'act_cost': 12.93,
  'quantity': 116},
 {'code': '0101021B0BEBEAL',
  'items': 10,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Gaviscon Advance_Liq (Peppermint) S/F',
  'nic': 64.0,
  'act_cost': 59.45,
  'quantity': 6250},
 {'code': '0101021B0BIABAH',
  'items': 2,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Sod Algin/Pot Bicarb_Susp S/F',
  'nic': 3.9,
  'act_cost': 3.64,
  'quantity': 1000},
 {'code': '0102000A0AAAAAA',
  'items': 1,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'name': 'Alverine Cit_Cap 60mg',
  'nic': 19.48,
  'act_cost': 18.05,
  'quantity': 100}]
```

I have been able to identify the number of unique `values` for 'name' but I do not know how to proceed from there. Here is the code I used:

```
names =[]

for item in range(len(json_data)):
    names.append(json_data[item]['name'])

names=set(names)
names=list(names)

print(len(names))
```

I expect the `output` to be in the following format:

```
most_common = [("", 0)]
```

with the name in quotes followed by the total sum of items.
e.g:

```
most_common = [("Gaviscon Advance_Liq (Peppermint) S/F", 36)]
```

Please bear with me. I am new to Stackoverflow and this is my first question so I'm still trying to get used to how to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Counter`. It is a class from `collections` module that allows you to easily count how many times each item appears in a collection.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> name_numbers = Counter()
>>> for item in json_data:
...     name_numbers[item['name']] += item['items']
...
>>> name_numbers
Counter({'Gaviscon Advance_Liq (Peppermint) S/F': 36, 'Sod Algin/Pot Bicarb_Susp S/F': 14, 'Sod Alginate/Pot Bicarb_Tab Chble 500mg': 3, 'Co-Magaldrox_Susp 195mg/220mg/5ml S/F': 2, 'Alginate_Raft-Forming Oral Susp S/F': 1, 'Alverine Cit_Cap 60mg': 1})
>>> name_numbers.most_common(1)
[('Gaviscon Advance_Liq (Peppermint) S/F', 36)]
```

Comment: Thank you Gelineau. Sorry I put 4 for the number of items in the example I gave in the question. From the given data the number of items should be 36 i.e we first split the data according to 'name' and then find which group has the highest number of 'item'(i.e we sum the 'item' numbers in each group to find the group that has the highest number of items)